# STS Dynamic project does not build

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, build, sts

When I try to build/Run the project, it keeps refusing to build with this error:
[The error is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cShe0.png)

I tried fixing the JDK path but still did not work

you can also see that all of the projects have the same issue

Can someone please help me solve this issue

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this, and which version of Java is running it?